# Windows 8.1 Universal DatePicker styling

Tags: xaml, datepicker, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I am struggling to find a way to style the appearance of the Windows 8.1 Universal DatePicker. I would like to remove the borders of the input control (except the bottom border).

With a combobox or textbox setting the BorderThickness = "0 0 0 1" achieves the desired effect. This however doesn't make any impact on the datepicker.

Does this need to be done through the use of Control Templates and if so, where can one find reference to which properties can be changed to achieve the desired effect? Or is there a simpler way of getting it done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I came right by doing the following:

1. Started new project (blank universal 8.1)
2. Added DatePicker control to a form.
3. Extracted the template by 'Edit Template' & 'Edit a copy'
4. The template is then added to the app.xaml
5. Edit the styling as needed there.
6. The styling I needed was done on the FlyoutButton BorderThickness="0 0 0 1"